# Ouput Server Name Along With InstallState of Service

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell. I have the following simple little script:

```
$serversall = (Get-Content ".\Servers.txt")  
foreach($vm in $serversall){ 
  Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server -ComputerName $vm | 
  Select-Object InstallState |
  Export-Csv -path E:\Scripts\Output\IISWebServersStatus.csv -Append
}
```

This just gives me one column to let me know if the status is "Installed" or "Available". I want another column that would also show the server name next to the status of the service. Any idea how I would accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach:

```
$serversall = (Get-Content ".\Servers.txt")
$output = @()
foreach($vm in $serversall) { 
  $installed = (Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server -ComputerName $vm).InstallState
  $output += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{'ComputerName'=$vm; 'Status'=$installed }
}

$output | Export-Csv -path E:\Scripts\Output\IISWebServersStatus.csv -Append
```

Create an array, `$output` that you can use to store all the information. On each loop iteration, build an object that holds the the server name and the install state and append it to the output array.

After the loop is done, write the output array to the csv file.

Doing one file write at the end will save on i/o operations, so could save time. In this example, `Get-WindowsFeature` is a relatively slow operation so it probably makes little difference, but good to understand the theory nonetheless.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!